# Will cache warming in atg work for sub-type itemdecriptors and its properties?

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo

I am precaching the productcatalog items on server startup. But after BCC deployment, the cache is getting cleared. Cachewarming is enabled but doesnt look like helping. Anyone knows about how to reload the cache after BCC deployment? The items are subtypes of existing itemdescriptor.

Comment: Is it only the sub-types that don't get reloaded or everything? Which version of ATG and are you using Switching Schemas?

Answer (score 0):

[From Oracle Commerce Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52191_03/Platform.11-1/ATGContentAdminProgGuide/html/s1114cachewarmingbehavior01.html): By default, the cache warming service will only load repository item properties from primary tables. If you want to load repository item properties from auxiliary or multi-type tables include those properties in the extraProperties configuration property in CacheWarmingServiceConfiguration.